# HttpServletRequest::getRemoteUser() return NULL

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a pretty simple servlet running on JBoss 7.1 AS. I'm using Java EE via Eclipse Kepler. All is running fine with it.

I now want to add some authentification. I've done a ton of reading and to be honest I'm overwhelmed with it all. Here are my, actually pretty simple, requirememnts:

1) If I could get HttpServletRequest::getRemoteUser() to return the user to me, I would be done. I have my own method of authentification.

2) I do NOT want to have the user prompted for User and Password.

Really, that is it. I want to do my own authentication BUT I need to know the USER. No password, no nothing... Just USER.
I believe the USER is his logged in name to the OS...

I think that is all I need to say. I'm not sure how I should go about implementing this.

Since I'm no Java/JBoss expert, please respond to me as such! :) I cannot be offended!!!

Thanks!

Dave P

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong: The user is not just the OS user.

JBoss is a process on some computer. As that it has to be running as some user known to the os on that computer. Your java application can retrieve that user name via `System.getProperty("user.name")`.

But be aware that JBoss listens on HTTP/HTTPS network traffic. So someone - not necessarily the OS user - can connect to the system. How should JBoss know which user connected? That's what authentication is for.

Usually authentication involves asking for username (claim) and password (proof). If you want to circumvent that and trust any user to provide the correct name, use a form-based authentication with a form not asking for password, and configure a realm that does not have to match a password to allow users in.

To implement alternative authentication mechanisms it might be useful to look at tools like Keycloak.